# Using onMissingMethod cannot access object variables

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, railo

In CF10, I want to access a variable Test object using onMissingMethod function in TestHelper object, but I am getting an error.

Test.cfc

```
component  {

public Any function init(){
    instance = { x = 1 };
    return this;
}

public numeric function getX(){

    return instance.x;

}

}
```

TestHelper.cfc

```
component  {

public Any function init( ){
    variables.testObj = new Test();
    return this;
}

public any function onMissingMethod( required string missingMethodName, required struct missingMethodArguments ){

    var func = variables.testObj[ arguments.missingMethodName ];
    return func( argumentCollection = arguments.missingMethodArguments );

}

}
```

Calling the object

```
obj = new TestHelper();
writeOutput( obj.getX() );  //Element INSTANCE.X is undefined in VARIABLES
```

In CF10, this gives me an error that element X is undefined in instance.  It doesn't seem to recognize the variable instance.  I could explicitly define getX function in TestHelper, but I was hoping I could use the onMissingMethod function.

Am I misunderstanding how onMissingMethod supposed to work here?  FWIW, the code works in Railo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your issue, I'm surprised this code runs on Railo. I don't think it should.

The issue is with this code:

```
var func = variables.testObj[ arguments.missingMethodName ];
return func( argumentCollection = arguments.missingMethodArguments );
```

Here you are pulling the function `getX()` out of `variables.testObj`, and running it in the context of your `TestHelper` instance. And that object doesn't have a `variables.x. Hence the error.

You need to put your `func` reference into `variables.testObj`, not pull `getX` out of it. So like this:

```
var variables.testObj.func = variables.testObj[ arguments.missingMethodName ];
return variables.testObj.func( argumentCollection = arguments.missingMethodArguments );
```

That way you're running `func()` (your proxy to `getX()`) in the correct context, so it will see `variabales.x.`

Given this situation, there's no way this code should work on Railo (based on the info you've given us being all the relevant info, anyhow).

Comment: Adam, you are right (as usual).  When I tested it in Railo, I was actually doing `return variables.testObj[ arguments.missingMethodName ] ( argumentCollection = arguments.missingMethodArguments );`.  But CF10 does not like this code, so I thought I could just assign the method to a variable func and then call it on the next line.  I didn't realize that doing so takes the method out of its context.  Thanks for the clarification.  Much appreciated.

Comment: No probs. Yeah, we tried to get Adobe to add that syntax, but they wouldn't. There is `invoke()` though, which might help? https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Invoke